# Rails Routes deprecation warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails 4.2.1 application and got a deprecation warning in my routes.rb

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Defining a route where `to` is a controller without an action is deprecated. Please change `to: :super_admin` to `controller: :super_admin`. (called from block in <top (required)>
```

routes looks like this:

```
 get "/super_admin(/:action(/:id))", :to => "super_admin", :constraints => {:subdomain => "admin"}
 get "/", :to => redirect("/super_admin"), :constraints => {:subdomain => "admin"}
 get "/super_admin(/:action(/:id))", :to => "super_admin", :constraints => {:subdomain => "admin.staging"}
 get "/", :to => redirect("/super_admin"), :constraints => {:subdomain => "admin.staging"}
 get "/super_admin(/:action(/:id))", :to => redirect("/")
```

what do I have to change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `controller: :super_admin` instead of `to: :super_admin`. This is also mentioned in the deprecation warning message.

Comment: really correct is this: `:controller => :super_admin` but thanks for the hint!